# Why won't my True statement work?

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary

Here is a dictionary:

```
Vocab ={'Adherent' : " supporter; follower.",
'Incoherent' : "without logical or meaningful connection; disjointed; rambling",
'Inherent' : "existing in someone or something as a permanent and inseparable element, quality, or attribute"}
```

I've created a simple set of if statements in a loop:

```
while 1:
    x = Vocab[random.choice(Vocab.keys())]
    print x
    t1=raw_input("What word matches this definition?: ")
    if t1 in Vocab == True:
        if Vocab[t1] == x:
            print "That's correct!"
        elif Vocab[t1] != x:
            print "That's wrong!"
    else:
        print "That's not a word!"
    raw_input("Hit 'enter': ")
```

For some strange reason, when the user inputs a key that is in the dictionary, the code outputs:

```
"That's not a word"
```

Why isn't the if statement with the '== True' working?

Comment: please indent your code properly

Comment: Are you on Windows? ``raw_input`` may not be properly stripping the ``\r`` at the end of the input line. Also, you can just do ``if t1 in Vocab``, no need for the extra ``True`` bit.

Comment: You can write `if t1 in Vocab:` as well. Extra comparison (`==True`) is not neccesary.

Comment: @ariusdante Yes i am on windows

Comment: You should change `if t1 in Vocab == True:` with: `if t1 in Vocab:` and second, try to search for `t1.strip()`

Comment: What, problem solved? :)

Comment: The issue is with operands precedence...

Comment: it could have been something with the compiler.  Maybe it parsed 'Vocab == True' first which was probably 'True' then checked to see 'if t1 in True'

Comment: Please mark as solved by choosing an answer

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use `if t1 in Vocab == True`, simply use `if t1 in Vocab`.

The problem is the operand precedence. The `==` has priority over `in`, so when you write `if t1 in Vocab == True` python interprets as `if t1 in (Vocab == True)`.

To fix the precedence issue, you can write like this: `if (t1 in Vocab) == True:`, but again there is no need to compare if the result of `t1 in Vocab` is `True`, simple use this:

```
if t1 in Vocab:
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use the "== True." Python should evaluate the if statement when you use this syntax without that.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. First, if you're on Windows, there is the possibility that it might not be stripping the `'\r'` at the end of the input line, or you might have extra whitespace in general from your input. But also, you can simplify your code significantly, as so:

```
    t1=raw_input("What word matches this definition?: ")
    try:
        if Vocab[t1.strip()] == x:  # This should fix your 'not a word' problem
            print "That's Correct"!
        else:
            print "That's Wrong!"!
    except KeyError:
        print "That's not a word!"
```

There's no need to test if a key is in a dictionary before using it. Simply try and use it and then catch the resulting `KeyError`.

*edit*

@MagnunLeno is also totally correct about the precedence problem, although simplifying your code as I have recommended makes it a moot point.